# I get errorTypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'questionEl.innerText = `What is ${num1}multip...`')

Tags: javascript

please help me with this, I marked where the error is, and I don't know if it matters but I'm using a Mac.

```
const num2 = Math.ceil(Math.random()*10)

const questionEl = document.getElementById("question")

const inputEl = document.getElementById("input")

questionEl.innerText = `What is ${num1}multiply by ${num2}?`; //error

const formEl = document.getElementById("form");

let score = 0;

const correctAns = num1 * num2;

formEl.addEventListener("submit", ()=>{
    const userAns = +inputEl.value
    if(userAns === correctAns){
        score++
        console.log(score)
    } else{
        score--
        console.log(score)

    }
});
```

Comment: Did you define num1 variable like num2? Or are you getting input from user in the inputE1?

Comment: yes,but questionEl.innerText... is the problem, it messages TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'questionEl.innerText = `What is ${num1} multiply by ${num2}?`') in the console